# SQL "First relevant day"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with `opening_hours` for restaurants:

```
SELECT * FROM opening_hours;
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
| id | restaurant_id | start_time | end_time | day |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
|  1 |             1 | 12:00:00   | 18:00:00 |   1 |
|  2 |             1 | 09:00:00   | 19:00:00 |   4 |
|  3 |             2 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   4 |
|  4 |             2 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   5 |
|  5 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   4 |
|  6 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   5 |
|  7 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   1 |
|  8 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   6 |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaea09/1

Now I want to fetch the "closest" next day or same day for every restaurant to the current day. For example when the current day is `1` the result would be:

```
restaurant_id: 1 day: 1
restaurant_id: 2 day: 4
restaurant_id: 3 day: 1
```

In the case of day `1` I could do this:

```
SELECT day FROM opening_hours WHERE day >= 1 GROUP BY restaurant_id LIMIT 1
```

But if today would be `6` that would not work. I would need the query to go get the maximum number of days (`7`) and if that could not be found it should start trying from `1` again. So the result for day `6` would be in this case:

```
restaurant_id: 1 day: 1
restaurant_id: 2 day: 4
restaurant_id: 3 day: 6
```

How could I achieve this with a query?

I'd think it could be something like this in pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT `day` FROM opening_hours WHERE `day` >= 'today' IF NOT FOUND WHERE `day` >= 1 GROUP BY `restaurant_id` LIMIT 1
```

edit:

I could run 2 queries, and determine if a match for a restaurant was found in the first. If not, run a second query. But there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested, this one works :) you can keep it simple.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    oh.*
    FROM
    opening_hours oh
    ORDER BY restaurant_id, 
    `day` + IF(`day` < $current_day, 7, 0)
) sq
GROUP BY restaurant_id;
```

**Explanation:**

Note though, that this is a bit hacky. To select a column that is not used in the `group by` and has no aggregate function applied to it, usually isn't allowed, because theoretically it could give you a random row of each group. That's why it's not allowed in most database systems. MySQL is actually the only one I know of, that allows this (if not set otherwise via sql-mode). Like I said, in theory. Practically it's a bit different and if you do an `order by` in the subquery, MySQL will always give you the minimum or maximum value (depending on the sort order).

**Tests:**

Desired result with current day = 1:

```
root@VM:playground > SELECT * FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->     oh.*
    ->     FROM
    ->     opening_hours oh
    ->     ORDER BY restaurant_id,
    ->     `day` + IF(`day` < 1, 7, 0)
    -> ) sq
    -> GROUP BY restaurant_id;
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
| id | restaurant_id | start_time | end_time | day |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
|  1 |             1 | 12:00:00   | 18:00:00 |   1 |
|  3 |             2 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   4 |
|  7 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   1 |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Desired result with current day = 6:

```
root@VM:playground > SELECT * FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->     oh.*
    ->     FROM
    ->     opening_hours oh
    ->     ORDER BY restaurant_id,
    ->     `day` + IF(`day` < 6, 7, 0)
    -> ) sq
    -> GROUP BY restaurant_id;
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
| id | restaurant_id | start_time | end_time | day |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
|  1 |             1 | 12:00:00   | 18:00:00 |   1 |
|  3 |             2 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   4 |
|  8 |             3 | 09:00:00   | 16:00:00 |   6 |
+----+---------------+------------+----------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do it:

```
SELECT oh1.*
-- set the start day
FROM (SELECT @start := 1) AS start,
-- calculate difference in days
     (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN day-@start >= 0 THEN day-@start ELSE day-@start+7 END) AS diff
      FROM opening_hours) AS oh1
-- find minimum difference
JOIN (SELECT restaurant_id, MIN(CASE WHEN day-@start >= 0 THEN day-@start ELSE day-@start+7 END) AS min_diff
      FROM opening_hours
      GROUP BY restaurant_id) AS oh2
  ON oh1.restaurant_id = oh2.restaurant_id AND
     oh1.diff = oh2.min_diff
```

Replace `@start := 1` with your starting day or a call to `DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())`, depending on how you want to do it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one.

Best I can come up with is this, which seems to work but I might be missing some edge cases.

```
SELECT sub0.restaurant_id, MIN(sub1.day)
FROM
(
    SELECT restaurant_id, MIN( LEAST(ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - day), ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - (day + 7)), ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - (day - 7)))) AS difference
    FROM opening_hours 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id
) sub0
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT restaurant_id, day,  LEAST(ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - day), ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - (day + 7)), ABS(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) - (day - 7))) AS difference
    FROM opening_hours 
) sub1
ON sub0.restaurant_id = sub1.restaurant_id
AND sub0.difference = sub1.difference
GROUP BY sub0.restaurant_id
```

The first sub query is getting the absolute difference between todays day and each restaurant day. It is using the day, the day plus 7 and the day minus 7  to compare with, using ABS to just get the difference in days and using LEAST to get the lowest of those differences. This way if the current day is 1 and there is a restaurant day of 6 it is comparing 1 + 7 with 6, 1 - 7 with 6 and 1 with 6 and getting the least of those (in this case that would be 1 + 7).

The 2nd sub query just gets that difference and the day of the week for each possible restaurant / day, and this is joined to the first sub query.

The outer query uses MIN just to pick a single day when 2 are just as close.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to simply add 7 to the result of your day difference calculation when the day is less than the day you are searching for:

```
SET @Day = 6;
SELECT  ID, Restaurant_id, Day,
        CASE WHEN Day < @Day THEN 7 ELSE 0 END + Day - @Day AS DaysFromNow
FROM    opening_hours;
```

This will give:

```
ID  RESTAURANT_ID   DAY     DAYSFROMNOW
1   1               1       2
2   1               4       5
3   2               4       5
4   2               5       6
5   3               4       5
6   3               5       6
7   3               1       2
8   3               6       0
```

Then to get the next relavant day you need to get the minimum `DaysFromNow` for each restaurant, then join back to your main table:

```
SET @Day = 6;
SELECT  o.*
FROM    opening_hours AS o
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Restaurant_id, 
                    MIN(CASE WHEN Day < @Day THEN 7 ELSE 0 END + Day - @Day) AS DaysFromNow
            FROM    opening_hours
            GROUP BY Restaurant_id
        ) AS mo
            ON mo.Restaurant_id = o.Restaurant_id
            AND mo.DaysFromNow = (CASE WHEN Day < @Day THEN 7 ELSE 0 END + Day - @Day);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaea09/19)**